# does it sound like a native when we say "Do not leave / put your scooter untidily in the middle of the living room like that"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

does it sound like a native when we say "**Do not leave / put your scooter untidily in the middle of the living room like that, please put it in the corner of the room**"?

I am not a native, so sometimes my expression sounds like in textbook.

**How would you (native speakers) express in that situation?**

Comment: In my opinion, most native speakers are likely to put the "please" first when giving an instruction as it is most polite, but it depends who they are speaking to.   A native speaker would be likely to use "don't" rather than "do not" because its shorter and easier to say, and similarly they are likely to leave out "untidily" because its an awkward and unusual word that is difficult to say.  its also possible to drop some words that may not be necessary - so use "room" instead of living room if it is obvious, and drop "of the room" at the end because the instruction is likely to be clear

Comment: with it.  So a shortened version spoken by a native speaker might be: "Please don't leave your scooter in the middle of the [living] room like that - put it in the corner."

Comment: "Do not leave / put your scooter untidily in the middle of the living room like that, please put it in the corner of the room" - this sounds like a character, "[Victorian Dad](http://viz.co.uk/category/victorian-dad/)", in a British satirical comic called _Viz_.